# How to find multiple lines from file with PHP?

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP script to search for a few lines in a pcap file. This pcap file will be piped through tail -> PHP.

I need to find a few lines like (Host: www.google.com) or (Domain: amazon.com) etc..

I'm new with PHP and struggling to get this code working, the actual output of all the fetched data need to be inserted into a SQL DB. I've used regex to filter out the binary stuff from the pcap.

I've tried multiple loops like the wile, foreach, for, but I'm not getting the clue how to do this in my script.

The code that I have so far is:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$line = fgets ($handle, 1000);

$search1 = 'Location';
$search2 = 'Host:';
$search3 = 'User';
$search4 = 'Cookie';
$search5 = 'Domain:';

$matches = array();

$regex = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\D\#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/';

if ($handle){
    while ($handle) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($buffer, $search1) !== FALSE) {
            $res = preg_replace($regex, "", $buffer);
            $matches[] = $res;
            print_r($res). "\n";
        }
    } 
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

I've read many posts on the internet, but couldn't find any solution or I've not enough knowledge about PHP to get this done. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How does the content of the file look like? Can you give a short example of a few lines from the file?

Comment: It's hard to open the raw data of a pcap, it looks like:

���?�����UԙI5�A%��X�\������f̕s��ߌ��䷀��0c��y�%��4����w��u��lG�2��v��������@�Iww4������Ei,'@��
���?�����U*CI5

I can already turn this into readable format for php using the regex.

Comment: Try to write echo in last if it’s going in there check pls

Comment: @samuhay what do you mean?

Comment: Just check your conditions are they working properly

Comment: The script how it is now works fine for 1 $search, but I have to get all of the $search[1-5] items as a output and I don't know how to combine or do multiple searches in this script. @samuhay

Comment: so you can create a array from this search items and you can use foreach for total search i will post an ansfer for it just a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working for first then loop it think about algorithm always

```
$handle = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$line = fgets ($handle, 1000);

$search = ['Location','Host:','User','Cookie','Domain:'];
$matches = array();
$regex = '/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\D\#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/';

if ($handle){
    while ($handle) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        foreach($search as $seek){
            if(strpos($buffer, $seek) !== FALSE) {
                $res = preg_replace($regex, "", $buffer);
                $matches[] = $res;
                print_r($res). "\n";
            }
        }

    } 
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked for me! Many thanks, had so many days trying to get this working also with the foreach loop, but I've no experience in PHP.

Comment: No problem bro you can check some basics from w3school and PHP official documentation